# Как сделать чтобы открывался только один details

Tags: javascript, html

подскажите, как сделать с помощью JS чтобы открывался только один пункт

```html
<details>
<summary>Пункт 1</summary>
скрытый текст
</details>
<details>
<summary>Пункт 2</summary>
скрытый текст
</details>
<details>
<summary>Пункт 3</summary>
скрытый текст
</details>
```

Comment: Он и так один открывается....  Не совсем понятен вопрос и смысл

Comment: @Air Скорее всего нужно, чтобы когда один открывался, второй закрывался..

Comment: Наверное............

Comment: Да, верно, один открывался, второй закрывался

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надеюсь вы так хотели.

```js
const details = document.querySelectorAll("details");

// добавить к каждому клику события клика
[...details].forEach((targetDetail) => {
  targetDetail.addEventListener("click", _ => {
    // закрывать всех кроме кликнутого
    details.forEach((detail) => {
      if (detail !== targetDetail) {
        detail.removeAttribute("open");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<details >
<summary>Пункт 1</summary>
скрытый текст
</details>
<details>
<summary>Пункт 2</summary>
скрытый текст
</details>
<details>
<summary>Пункт 3</summary>
скрытый текст
</details>
```